# Fixed height div pagination in html

Tags: layout, html, pagination

My website has a content div which has to be of specific height. Let's say 800px.

I'm looking for a way I could enter the content in that div and make the div break it up and make it available via some "next" anchors.

Is such thing possible in a regular html page, no wordpress no drupal no plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style your div with overflow:hidden;
Then add a button to make it scroll 800px down

You should also use overflow:scroll-y; to make it simple.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is there a recomended jquery plugin to use, Im building my site on html5boilerplate, there are thousands of jquery plugins out there, I would like to use a robust proven simple scroller :D

Comment: No need for a plugin, just code this simple thing yourself and you'll see the marvels of Jquery. You should be enough with 3 lines.

Comment: Im not good at jquery so Im looking for examples so I can learn from source. I stumbled upon this...http://gazpo.com/downloads/tutorials/jquery/horizontal_scroll/ but every slide on that page is another div...